Docker Login not using correct port
I am trying to login to a docker repo which is on port 11111 for example.
When i do a docker login docker login docker.reponame.domain:11111 (which has a valid certificate and confirmed).  I get an x509 certificate error and the path its using is:
GET https://docker.reponame.domain/v2/token...

It looks like it's not using the port 11111 which i need.  Any ideas on how to force this?  I have tried everything!
I have NO_PROXY and HTTP/S_PROXY set.
Thanks.

Your registry is misconfigured for token based authentication. You should be able to see the url from the authentication header in the output of:
curl -iL https://docker.reponame.domain:11111/v2/


Thanks for replying.
So i see the URL without the port on the WWW-Authenticate.  I am assuming this is wrong as it should have the port on?
So this is something that needs changing within nexus?  Thanks

Yes, the configuration of your registry would need to include the port number there.

Thanks a lot.  Yeah there was an issue on the nexus and had that sorted out for me.  Thanks
